# Cannot run docker-based Web App - doesn't respond to HTTP pings on port 80

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, port, streamlit

I have a Web App running in Azure inside a docker container. However, I am unable to access the application. Here is the log from "Deployment Center":

```
 docker run -d -p 8349:80 --name app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103 -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=app-my-web-app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=app-my-web-app.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=0a7710206f1bf4cc0f990b30fe5398a5e19747081c3fc5a2f68d99d5f89c7df1 mywebapp.azurecr.io/mywebapp:latest

2021-09-23T13:19:11.654Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-09-23T13:19:14.954Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103 for site app-my-web-app
2021-09-23T13:19:30.307Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 15.3528308 sec
2021-09-23T13:19:45.558Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 30.6041298 sec
2021-09-23T13:20:00.710Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 45.756227 sec
2021-09-23T13:20:16.272Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 61.3183851 sec
2021-09-23T13:20:31.463Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 76.508941 sec
2021-09-23T13:20:46.994Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 92.0402202 sec
2021-09-23T13:21:12.911Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 117.9568867 sec
2021-09-23T13:21:28.380Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 133.4261021 sec
2021-09-23T13:21:43.605Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 148.6510226 sec
2021-09-23T13:21:59.418Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 164.4641901 sec
2021-09-23T13:22:14.994Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 180.0399709 sec
2021-09-23T13:22:30.235Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 195.2811287 sec
2021-09-23T13:22:51.871Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103. Elapsed time = 216.9167296 sec
2021-09-23T13:23:05.306Z ERROR - Container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103 for site app-my-web-app did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3521527 sec
2021-09-23T13:23:05.392Z ERROR - Container app-my-web-app_0_bca7f103 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2021-09-23T13:23:05.442Z INFO - Stopping site app-my-web-app because it failed during startup.
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80 
RUN mkdir ~/.streamlit
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["my_web_app.py"]
```

Furthermore, I added the following "Application Settings" under configuration:

- Name=PORT, Value=80
- Name=WEBSITES_PORT, Value=80

I also tried to increase WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1800. Nothing works.

Any ideas to how this can be resolved? I have confirmed that the docker container builds and runs locally.

Comment: Can you reach the container on port 8349?

Comment: @Jacobian2450, 
By default, App Service assumes your custom container is listening on port 80. If your container listens to a different port, as in your case, you need set the WEBSITES_PORT (for customer containers) app setting only in your App Service app. As Hans mentioned above, you may add the port specified. 
Also, just to highlight the difference: app settings/variable- `PORT` (default) vs WEBSITES_PORT (For custom containers)- PORT variable is not necessary due to automatic port detection. If no port is detected, it defaults to 80.

Comment: The WEBSITES_PORT app setting does not have any effect within the container, and you can’t access it as an environment variable within the container.

For additional info: 
Kindly see the Supported and Unsupported Docker Compose options on App Service:
Only port 80 and 8080 is accessible (exposed ports) -App Service Linux FAQ
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux 

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options